# "Missing" glew32.dll - resides at C:\windows\system32\glew32.dll, regsvr32 fails

Tags: windows-7, path, dll, regsvr32

I have an application which relies on glew32.lib/.dll to run.  The .lib is in the VS2005 SDK directory and works fine for compiling.  The .dll have placed (via cmd.exe run as Administrator) in C:\windows\system32.

When I attempt to run the application, it tells me that glew32.dll is not on the computer.

I've attempted to register the dll via regsvr32.exe, which fails with the following message:

> The module "glew32.dll" failed to load.  Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files.
>
> The specified module could not be found.

I hit it with DependencyWalker and it's only direct dependency is opengl32.dll.  opengl32.dll is listed as missing two dependencies (well, dependencies of dependencies of dependencies of dependencies) - GPSVC.dll and IESHIMS.dll...  both exist, GPSVC.dll is in system32, IESHIMS.dll is in ../winsxs/x86_microsoft-windows-ie-ieshims-[hex (guid?)]

I went ahead and copied IESHIMS.dll to system32, but to no avail.  It still won't cooperate.

Thoughts (other than use linux where ldconfig would just work.. ;)?

Answer (score 1):

A good tool for tracking down problems like this one is [Sysinternals ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) (or the older SysInternals FileMon, which is available on some mirror sites and is easier to use).  With the proper filtering options, you'll be able to see what DLLs windows is trying to load (and from where).